# trying to verify compose an email using gmail account

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use Selenium web driver automation.
I'm trying to verify compose an email using gmail account.
I code it using `for` loop but it is only pass the gmail login but not compose even now after write the verification method.

```
public boolean verifySentMessageSuccess2(int i, String expectedMessage) throws InterruptedException {
    boolean flag = false;

    String xpath="//tbody/tr/td[6]/div/div/div/span/b";
    List<WebElement> mailSubject = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));


    for(int second = 0; second<=i; second++){
        if (second>=i){
            break;
        }
         for (WebElement elements : mailSubject) {
             if (mailSubject.contains(expectedMessage)) {
                 System.out.println("Mail is sent successfully. Mail is: " + mailSubject);
             flag = true;
             }
             }
             if (flag) {
                 System.out.println("Mail is not sent successfully.");
             break;
             }
             Thread.sleep(1000);
             }
    return flag;
}
```

Above is coded in the GmailComposePage class. And Following is the code relevant to GmailComposeTest Class

```
public void verifySendingEmail() throws Exception{
    GmailComposePage composePage = new GmailComposePage(driver);
    composePage.clickCompose();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    composePage.enterRecipient("tsumia@gmail.com");
    composePage.enterSubject("Selenium Web Driver Test");
    composePage.enterMessage("This is a sample web driver email");
    composePage.clickSend();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    composePage.navigateToInbox();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Assert.assertTrue(composePage.verifySentMessageSuccess2(20, "Selenium Web Driver Test"));
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

In the console I get this message when I run this

PASSED: verifyGmailLogin

FAILED: verifySendingEmail

But it should pass the both when run..

For further information below is my Xpath.. But there is no error in xpath

```
String row_xpath2 = "//tbody/tr/td[6]/div/div/div/span/b";
```

Comment: and what is the question here? or what error are u getting? or what issue are u facing

Comment: There are no errors when run..But it stops and browser get closed after a while login to the gmail account. (due to call driver.quite() method)  Composing a new mail is not working here.. So is there any mistake have I done in the verification part.

Comment: I need only to know whether this verification code and the  ' Assert.assertTrue(composePage.verifySentMessageSuccess2(20, "Selenium Web Driver Test"));' in the verifySendingEmail method are correct or wrong

Comment: it is a bit difficult to understand your code without proper working code snippet..so where things could have gone can be investigated only if you post a fully working example. Or better try to run your code in debug mode and see which step is failing. Not sure what "20" as argument stands for. is it an attempt to retry 20 times?

Comment: @MrunalGosar 
 
 
'20' is the number of mails that shown under my gmail inbox page... Is it correct to pass it as an argument? And I mention the xpath as well above.

Comment: Thats an absolute XPath which should never be used.. I suspect that to be the cause..I would suggest in such cases always try to run ur code in debug mode and inspect variables..they tell you everything that u need to know to find out where the issues lies

Answer (score 0):

Hope the xpath given is wrong. Since you are new to selenium, try below code which checks the entire page using **driver.getPageSource()**

Hence nothing wrong in your code except the xpath.

Try googling topics related to xpath.

```
public static boolean verifySentMessageSuccess2(int i, String expectedMessage) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        boolean flag = false;
        for(int second = 0; second<=i; second++)
        {
            if (second>=i)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (driver.getPageSource().contains(expectedMessage)) 
            {
                System.out.println("Mail is sent successfully. Mail is: " + expectedMessage);
                flag = true;
            }
            if (flag) 
            {
                System.out.println("Mail is sent successfully.");
                break;
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Comment: @MrunalGosar 
 
 
'20' is the number of mails that shown under my gmail inbox page... Is it correct to pass it as an argument? And I mention the xpath as well above in the question.